# Laravel collective form select returns option value - is this ok?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I am struggling with Laravel. I have a very weird problem and I am out of options:

my part of a form looks:

```
 <?php $listadzialow = \App\Dzial::lists('nazwa_dzialu')->toArray();
var_dump($listadzialow);
?>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('jakidzial','Jaki dział:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('jakidzial',$listadzialow,null,['placeholder'=>'Do jakiego działu należy','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'dzialselect']) !!}
    </div>

    <!-- Submit form button for Dodaj cykl -->
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::submit('Dodaj cykl',['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
```

After "submit" it goes to controller where I have function:

```
public function store()
 {
    $input = Request::all();
    $id = Request::get('dzialdlacyklu');
    $nazwa_cyklu = Request::get('nazwa_cyklu');
    var_dump($input);
 }
```

my form looks:
[my test form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI8Tx.png)

But the problem is that in var_dump($input) I see:

```
 array(3) { ["_token"]=> string(0) "" ["nazwa_cyklu"]=> string(12) "kolejny cykl" ["jakidzial"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

Which means that after submit, what is passed is value field of  instead of the text that is option (in my example string "Dzial").

1. Is this expected behaviour in php/laravel/eloquent/collective?
2. There is only one option in my select so I read somewhere that using toArray method provides you can get proper id of the element instead of array index. For 1st element it should read "1" not "0", I want this because in my database I have primary keys autoincremented from 1. When I look to source code:

`<select class="form-control" id="dzialselect" name="jakidzial"><option selected="selected" value="">Do jakiego działu należy</option><option value="0">Dział</option></select>`

So it looks first option is empty.
Forgive me If I am not clear. If there are any question, I will try to clarify as best as I can.

Comment: "Is this expected behaviour in php/laravel/eloquent/collective ?" That's the expected behaviour of HTML, actually. If you want to send the actual text values (of which I'm not a huge fan), you'll need to set the text values as the keys as well, or make another solution. As a beside, this is a great example of why it's good to write your code in English. It's just so much easier for other people to help you if your code is easy to read. Most of us don't speak... I'm guessing it's Polish? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the role of `value` attribute on a select option, so that's the expected behavior for anything that uses a Select, not an Laravel's or Collective's issue.

If you want to have the same value on option label and value, you will need to create a custom array keyed by the value!